# is it grammatical to say "what happened that..."?

Tags: relative-clauses

I have been using this construction "**what happened that...**", that clause being a relative clause, for so long. Now come to think of it, it doesn't sound grammatical. I mean, that clause is a relative clause, which requires an antecedent. But what clause is already a fused relative construction, or a noun phrase. Where is the antecedent?

Here are some examples

> What happened that made your organization and others decide to focus on this issue?

> What happened that softened you up a little bit?

Comment: Please give us an example of how you used it.

Comment: Without context, this question is meaningless. Any native speaker can come up with any number of contexts where these three words occur consecutively.

Comment: "What happened that made him say that?" What is the subject in your opinion?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. There are several ways you could correctly use "what happened that". Here are a couple of examples I can think of:

1. "What happened that night?"

As a *determiner*, "that" points to a specific 'night' which must have already been mentioned.

2. "What happened that was so bad you got upset?"

As a *pronoun*, you can use "that" to add information about the thing you have just mentioned. Even in a question where you don't know what the 'thing' is yet. Some*thing* happened, and you know it was bad.

I've made my examples questions, but of course the answers could begin with the same structure, eg "what happened that night was...."

Answer (score 1):

A typical example might be

> *What happened* [*that you are looking so worried*]?

No: it's not a relative construction at all.

The bracketed expression is a declarative content clause functioning as an adjunct to an interrogative clause. The content clause is introduced by the subordinator "that".

Semantically the adjunct can be regarded as resultative: the presuppositon of the question can be glossed as

*Something has happened with the result that you are looking worried*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say something in the way of 'this was what happened that changed everything,', I think that it should make sense, but I would avoid using it to start a sentence unless it's like 'what happened that changed everything was this; ------.', in which it might make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your examples are questions.

> What happened that made your organization and others decide to focus on this issue?
> What happened that softened you up a little bit?

Those use an interrogative *what*, not a fused relative *what*.

But, the construction still works with a fused relative *what*:

> No one knows what happened that could do this.

Either way, "what" works as an antecedent.

To my eye, "What that worries you happened?" is in canonical order, "What happened that worries you?" is in idiomatic order, and in either case the relative clause restricts the subject of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Your newly-added examples are good grammar and are natural English, and "what" is the antecedent. Consider the same sentence, but in statement form:

"**Something** happened that softened you up a little bit."

In this statement, "*that softened you up a little bit*" is a relative clause modifying "*something*", so "*something*" is the antecedent. In question form, the interrogative pronoun "*what*" takes the place of "*something*", and remains the antecedent of "*that*...".